# Import pdf into specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

There are lots of topics about this item, but I wasn't able to find an answer to my question. I want to select a pdf file and import all the text from this file into a specific sheet, let's call it sheet2. Please note this is a new pdf file every day, so it cannot come from a specific location, but the file has to be selected every day.

Any ideas?

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial site. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you can waver the limitation of using only VBA, you could use iText (combined with Apache POI). iText is more than capable of extracting the text from a pdf file, and the apache POI library allows you to generate Office documents (such as excel workbooks).